# Create child type during deserialization

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I got the following JSON document:

```
{
    "Title": "jkdjdjd",
    "Description": "dkfkkdd",
    "Actions": [{
                    "ActionType": "Email",
                    "Subject": "Bkdfkdk",
                    "Body": "kddkdkkd"
                }, {
                    "ActionType": "SMS",
                    "PhoneNumber": "+46333333"
                }
    ]
}
```

My classes looks like:

```
public class Trigger
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Action> Actions { get; set; }
}


public class Action
{
    public string ActionType { get; set; }
}

public class EmailAction : Action
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

public class SmsAction : Action
{
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

So what I basically want is to make JSON.NET select type of subclass depending on the name in the "ActionType". I know that JSON.NET supports a special field which can be used to identify the subclass. But I rather let the friendly name control which class to generate.

I've figured out that I should use a `CustomCreationConverter<Action>` for the selection. But I can't figure out how to read that field without screwing up the actual deserialization.

If it helps, I could use the following layout instead:

```
public class Action
{
    public string ActionType { get; set; }
    public ActionData Data { get; set; }
}

public ActionData
{
}

public class EmailData : ActionData
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

public class SmsData : ActionData
{
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

i.e. the JSON would be:

```
{
    "Title": "jkdjdjd",
    "Description": "dkfkkdd",
    "Actions": [{
                    "ActionType": "Email",
                    "Data": {
                        "Subject": "Bkdfkdk",
                        "Body": "kddkdkkd"
                    }
                }, {
                    "ActionType": "SMS",
                    "Data": {
                        "PhoneNumber": "+46333333"
                    }
                }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Not answering your question, but the in your JSON's root node you have the property `Title` and your `Trigger` class has the property `Name`. I think these should have the same property name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not bothered by having a `type` property included in the JSON you could use the setting of JsonSerializer `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto`.

Otherwise you can create a custom `JsonConverter` and adding it to the list of converters used during serialization. There is a good example in this post which worked well for me:

http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/json-deserialization-with-jsonnet-class.html

**EDIT:**

Does this not work for you as expected?
Have you tried making the `Action` base class abstract?

What is it that you tried in terms of the CreationConverter? How exactly does it not work - can you give some details on that?

```
public class JsonActionConverter : JsonCreationConverter<Action>
  {
    protected override Action Create(Type objectType, JObject jsonObject)
    {
      var typeName = jsonObject["ActionType"].ToString();
      switch(typeName)
      {
        case "Email":
          return new EmailAction();
        case "SMS":
          return new SMSAction();
        default: return null;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just write the `JsonConverter` needed to complete your answer. Otherwise it is just a comment.

Comment: Read the middle of my question. I've already addressed what you say

Comment: @jgauffin - See my edit and post some details in terms of errors / unexpected behaviour you're getting if that doesn't solve it.